# How to return a specific method on button click event?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, methods

Two buttons should update the value "PACK_LIB" inside "Stickers.java".

When they overwrite the String, the method setDefaultStickerPack() should be restarted.

When clicking on buttons b1 or b2 the value "PACK_LIB" will be overwritten by the value "allstickers" or "teststickers".

How can the button b1 or b2 restart the method "if(in==null) "inside setDefaultStickerPack() ?

-------KeyboardService.java

```
 final Button button2 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Stickers.PACK_LIB = "allstickers";
                stickers.setDefaultStickerPack();
                showStickers();
            }
        });

        final Button button3 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Stickers.PACK_LIB = "teststickers";
                stickers.setDefaultStickerPack();
                showStickers();
            }
        });
```

-------Stickers.java

```
public static String PACK_LIB ="";


public void setDefaultStickerPack() {
    checkVersion(true);
    InputStream in = null;
    String packList[]=new String[0];
    String PACK_APP="pack_app";
    String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
    String curAssets="";


    try {
        in = lContext.getAssets().open(PACK_APP+"/"+PACK_ICON);
        curAssets=PACK_APP;
        packList = lContext.getAssets().list(curAssets);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(in==null) {
        try {
            in = lContext.getAssets().open(PACK_LIB+"/"+PACK_ICON);
            curAssets=PACK_LIB;
            packList = lContext.getAssets().list(curAssets);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (in != null) {
        long packId = 1;
        PackData packData = new PackData();
        packData.objectId = packId;
        packData.name = "ROKOmoji";
        packData.iconOn = copyImgFile(in, "i" + packId + "_on");
        //packData.iconOff = copyImgFile(inOff, "i" + packId + "_off");
        List<StickerData> stickerData = new ArrayList<StickerData>();
        long i = 0;
        for (String img: packList) {
            if(PACK_ICON.equals(img)){
                continue;
            }
            InputStream sIs = null;
            try {
                sIs = lContext.getAssets().open(curAssets+"/"+img);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (sIs != null) {
                StickerData sd = new StickerData();
                i=i+1;
                File file = copyImgFile(sIs, "s" + img);
                sd.objectId = i;
                sd.imageId = i;
                sd.packId = packId;
                sd.packName = packData.name;
                sd.file = file;
                sd.iconKey = createIconKey(file, "si" + img);
                sd.mime = getMimeTypeOfFile(file.getPath());//"image/gif"
                sd.url = null;
                stickerData.add(sd);
            }
        }
        packData.stickers = stickerData;
        packDataListDefault.add(packData);
    }


}
```

Comment: Whats going wrong with your existing code?

Comment: "allstickers" includes 20 stickers and "teststickers" only 5 . 

When I click on the button "teststickers" the 5 stickers are shown under the 20 Stickers of "allstickers". And the 20 Stickers are invisible. So i need to scroll down to see the 5 stickers. @okcomputer_kid

Comment: Try making setDefaultStickerPack() as static and call Stickers.setDefaultStickerPack() rather than creating an instance stickers. ( I am not sure if this will help, I didn't understand completely)

Comment: How do I make setDefaultStickerPack() Static? because when I overwrite inside the code it says "Modifier not allowed here" @okcomputer_kid

Answer (score 0):

U can call the method with parameter. try with this.

-------KeyboardService.java

```
final Button button2 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stickers.setDefaultStickerPack("allstickers");
            showStickers();
        }
    });

    final Button button3 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stickers.setDefaultStickerPack("teststickers");
            showStickers();
        }
    });
```

-------Stickers.java

```
private static String PACK_LIB ="";

public void setDefaultStickerPack(String packLibValue) {
checkVersion(true);
InputStream in = null;
String packList[]=new String[0];
String PACK_APP="pack_app";
String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
String curAssets="";

PACK_LIB = packLibValue

try {
    in = lContext.getAssets().open(PACK_APP+"/"+PACK_ICON);
    curAssets=PACK_APP;
    packList = lContext.getAssets().list(curAssets);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(in==null) {
    try {
        in = lContext.getAssets().open(PACK_LIB+"/"+PACK_ICON);
        curAssets=PACK_LIB;
        packList = lContext.getAssets().list(curAssets);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

..........
..........

}
```

Comment: I tried it, but with the same result. I found out that when I close and launch the app again that it works. But can I restart the app when pressing a button? @M.S.T

Comment: yes definitely u can restart app during button click, just write this method and call it on button click
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

----
onRestart();
stickers.setDefaultStickerPack("allstickers");
showStickers();

but it would be bad coding, U can try with another way like add below line on ur AndroidManifest file 
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"